# Strange discrete math modulo question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here is the question in question. I don't know why but it makes my brain shut down when I look at it.

```
Let N = 12 = 2^2 + 2^3.

Given that M^2 $/equiv$ 51 (mod 59), what is M^12 (mod 59)?
```

Comment: exponent rules you know include ?

Comment: What does this have to do with N?

Answer (score 1):

Well $M^{12} = M^{2^2 +2^3} = M^{(2^2)}*M^{(2^3)}=$

$M^{2*2}* M^{2*2*2} \equiv (M^2)^2*((M^2)^2)^2\pmod {59}$.

Now $M^2 \equiv 51 \equiv -8\pmod {59}$

So $(M^2)^2 \equiv (-8)^2\equiv 64 \equiv 5\pmod {59}$

And $((M^2)^2)^2\equiv 5^2 \equiv 25\pmod {59}$ and so

$M^{12} \equiv (M^2)^2*((M^2)^2)^2 \equiv 5*25 \equiv 125 \equiv 7\pmod {59}$

---

Although to be honest I'd have just ignored the hint and done:

$M^2 \equiv 51 \equiv -8\pmod{59}$

$M^4 \equiv (-8)^2 \equiv 64\equiv  5\pmod{59}$

$M^6 \equiv (-8)*5\equiv -40 \pmod{59}$ so

$M^{12} \equiv (-40)^2 \equiv 1600 \pmod {59}$.

ANd

$1600 = 600 + 600 + 300 + 100=$

$10*60 + 10*60 + 5*60 + 60+ 40 \equiv$

$10*1 + 10*1 + 5*1 + 1 + (-19)\equiv$

$26-19\equiv 7\pmod {59}$

.....

or maybe I would have done $-40\equiv 19\pmod {59}$ and $19^2 \equiv (20 -1)^2 \equiv 400- 40+1\equiv 400 + 19+ 1\equiv 420 \equiv (-17)*10 \equiv -170 \equiv -118-52\equiv -52 \equiv 7\pmod{59}$ ...

... or maybe I wouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

(i). If $A_1\equiv A_2 \mod C$ and $A_2\equiv A_3 \mod C$ then $A_1\equiv A_3 \mod C.$

(ii). If $A\equiv B \mod C$ and $A'\equiv B' \mod C$ then $A+B\equiv A'+B'\mod C$ and $AB\equiv A'B'\mod C.$

(iii). If $A\equiv B \mod C$ and $n\in \Bbb N$ then $A^n\equiv B^n\mod C.$

Applying as much of (i),(ii),(iii) as often as possible, we have, modulo $59$ that  $$M^2\equiv 51\implies$$ $$\implies M^2\equiv -8\implies$$ $$\implies M^{12}\equiv (M^2)^6\equiv (-8)^6\equiv$$ $$\equiv ((-8)^2)^3\equiv 64^3\equiv$$ $$\equiv 5^3\equiv 5^3-2(59)\equiv 7.$$